# Nested sql joins process explanation needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to understand the process of nested join clauses in sql queries. Can you explain this example with pseudo codes? (What is the order of joining tables?)

```
  FROM 
table1 AS t1 (nolock)
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 (nolock)
        INNER JOIN table3 as t3 (nolock)
        ON t2.id = t3.id
    ON t1.mainId = t2.mainId
```

Comment: You do not control the 'order' of joins unless you use join hints (which by the way is a VERY BAD idea). Basically the query optimiser of your RDBMS will examine the query, consider indexes, and table statistics and determine an appropriate query plan to return the requested data.

Comment: PS: Please be wary of using `nolock` hints; you expose yourself to data integrity issues when you do. Based on the question you asked, I have my doubts whether you are fully aware of the nuances as to when it is safe/acceptable to use `nolock` hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQl basically we have 3 ways to join two tables.

Nested Loop ( Good if one table has small number of rows), 
Hash Join (Good if both table has very large rows, it does expensive hash formation in memory)
Merge Join (Good when we have sorted data to join).

From your question it seems that you want for Nested Loop.

Let us say t1 has 20 rows, t2 has 500 rows.

Now it will be like

For each row in t1
   Find rows in t2 where t1.MainId = t2.MainId

Now out put of that will be joined to t3.

Order of Joining depends on Optimizer, Expected Row count etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try `EXPLAIN query`.

It tells you exactly what's going on. :)

Of course that doesn't work in SQL Server. For that you can try [Razor SQLServer Explain Plan](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/sqlserver_explain_plan.html)

Or even [SET SHOWPLAN_ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259203(SQL.80).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, Sql server does not have this "EXPLAIN" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server Query Analyzer, look for "Show [Execution Plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx)" under the "Query" menu, and enable it.